# Why is smartscreen.exe trying to create `Bob the Builder - Bob Builds a Park.exe` on my computer?

Tags: windows-10

I just finished using the Sysinternals tool called procmon.exe to determine which files were being used during a program's installation. I used the procmon filters to show me only file events in a certain folder.

When the installer completed I started looking through the events and found that smartscreen.exe was trying to create files that I've never had on my computer let alone have never existed within the folder I'm monitoring.

Here are some sample events:

```
12:43:14.7269348 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\Connectix Virtual PC.msi  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7272922 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\Rail Simulator_uninst.exe NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7274143 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\Firewall\TVdriverSetup.exe    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7274937 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\Firewall\FwInstall.exe    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7338800 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\camware\camware.exe   PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7339694 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\camware\camware.exe   PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7340549 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\QuickCam\camware.exe  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7341375 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\QuickCam\QuickCam.exe PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7342453 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\QuickCam\Temp\LVIHlp.dll  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7343412 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\QCDriver\qcinsenu.dll PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7344183 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\QCDriver\qcinsenu.dll PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7344925 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\QuickCam\QuickCam.exe PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7345752 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\program files\Logitech\QuickCam\QuickCam.exe  PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7467868 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\Fur Fighters PC.msi   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
12:43:14.7450914 PM smartscreen.exe 10356   CreateFile  C:\BCTEMP\Bob the Builder - Bob Builds a Park.exe   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
```

Comment: There's [a similar question on Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/any-exe-called-setupexe-opens-some-300-non/8d16d136-e1e1-4e0c-8c33-2083258ce061) with some inconclusive information. If I'm reading the log right, CreateFile in this case is trying to read the file, not create it.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking the CreateFile had more to do with reading than writing but didn't know for sure. My Google Fu is bad because I didn't find anything about this from searching. Whoops.

This is probably some kind of built-in check so I don't think I'll worry too much about it.

Comment: According to one answer there, it may be Windows trying to figure out which compatibility settings to pick. It is certainly a weird behaviour.